# Get SWT widget at location

Tags: java, swt, coordinates, composite

I have a set of x/y coordinates relative to a composite, how do find what widget those coords fall in?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are the widgets children of the parent Composite that you know the coordinates of?  Or are they elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite ugly but you can do a function like this :

```
public Control getControl(Composite composite, int x, int y)
{
  Control control = null;
  Control[] children = composite.getChildren()
  if (children.length == 0)
     control = composite;
  else
    for (Control tmp : children) {
       // The check below will not work because x, y and the control's bounds could be
       // relative to different parents... Better to convert all coordinates to display
       // by using Control.toDisplay() and then compare below
       if (tmp.getBounds().contains(x, y)) 
       {
         if (control instanceof Composite)
             control = getControl(tmp, x, y);
         else
             control =  tmp;
         break;
       }

    }

  return control;
}
```

If you get the coordinates using a MouseListener, you can simply use :

```
event.getSource();
```

Comment: The comment about toDisplay() was helpful

Comment: If x and y are relative to the Display, then you need to translate them to Control coordinates, for this use: `Point dropPoint = tmp.toControl(x + tmp.getBounds().x, y + tmp.getBounds().y);` and then invoke `getBouds().contains(dropPoint)`